# how to load syncfusion essential scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, syncfusion

I am using Telerik open access and I want to load syncfusion essential scheduler,I want to make scheduler as read only.
and I want to display specific schedule of a person with specific id value,so I want to know how to pass parameter to action method to load the schedule with specific id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve your requirements using “Ajax.BeginFormExt “with Partial View. Please refer the below codes
View Page:

```
        <%using (Ajax.BeginFormExt("SubmitButton", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Schedule", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
          { %>
        <%=Html.TextBox("ownerID")%>
        <input type="submit" id="btn_subit" value="submit" class="Button" width="75px" />enter code here
        <% } %>
        <div id="Schedule">
            <% Html.Rende`enter code here`rPartial("SchedulerView"); %>
        </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
    public ActionResult SubmitButton(SchedulePropertiesModel model, int ownerID)
    {
        ViewData["data"] = FilterScheduleData(ownerID);
        return PartialView("SchedulerView",model);
    }

    private List<Appointments> FilterScheduleData(int ownerID)
    {
        var query = context.Appointments.Where(p => p.Owner == ownerID);
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: id value is passing to the controller and in the query I am able to see that particular record.After this in my view page at the syncfusion schedule code,"Invalid cast Exception unhandled by user code" exception is coming